# Code to display application log messages within an Android App

Tags: android, logging, android-logcat

My Android application posts many log messages. I am trying to display all these log messages within the same application. Application has a UI element (Text view), which should list all the messages logged by my application. How can I access the log messages, filtered by my application name (for example by name `com.mycompany.myapp`)

Comment: Be more specific on your question.

Comment: @user370305 dont you want to disclose yourself? :D :)

Comment: In Eclipse, or on a device (inside of your actual application)?

Comment: To display all logs related to my app.

Comment: inside my application not on eclipse

Answer (score 3):

To display the system log inside your application, filtered for your own application-name, you could insert the following as an inner class:

```
private static final String LogCatCommand = "logcat ActivityManager:I *:S";
private static final String ClearLogCatCommand = "logcat -c";

 private class MonitorLogThread extends Thread{
    public MonitorLogThread(){
    }

    BufferedReader br;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Process process;
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ClearLogCatCommand);
                process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(LogCatCommand);
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                // Check if it matches the pattern
                while(((line=br.readLine()) != null) && !this.isInterrupted()){

                // Filter for your app-line
                if (line.contains("your-filter-string")){
                    Log.i("myAppTag", "Found log-entry for my app:" + line);
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And in your onCreate-Method:

```
  Thread mThread = new MonitorLogThread();
  mThread.start();
```

You may have to adapt this example to make it work properly!

Comment: I want to display apps log info by coding.